# How to use wifiwizard codorva plugin

Tags: ionic2, wifi, cordova-plugins

I just want to scan list of available Wi-Fi networks and connect to desired one, then send data from an ionic2 app.
 I tried with few plugins but, couldn't use them in ioni2 app, so found [this cordova wifiwizard](https://github.com/hoerresb/WifiWizard) and installed it .but, when I tried using that got some errors, could anyone sort out what was going wrong

```
getScanResult() {
    WifiWizard.getScanResults(this.listHandler2, fail);
    console.log();
}
listHandler2(a) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
}

<button (click)="getScanResult();">Get Scan result</button>
```

When I tried the above code stuck with the error:

> Cannot find name 'WifiWizard'

So I tried like this.

```
window.WifiWizard.getScanResults(this.listHandler2, fail);
```

Got the error:

> Property "WifiWizard" does not exist on type "Window"

Comment: it looks like the last commit in that repo was 2 years ago.. maybe check http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/hotspot/

Comment: yeah,i too looked in to the "hotspot" but, i couldn't find any read,write methods ,so that i can send data or receive data from others

Comment: could you please tell me how to use "ping" callback of hotspot  native

Comment: from the link it would be .. `this.hotspot.pingHost().then(info=>{console.log(info)});`

Comment: its syntax is `this.hotspot.pingHost(ip,succesCB,failureCB)` .because when i used just `this.hotspot.pingHost().then(() => console.log());` i got error like supplied parameters were n't enough.

Comment: that is if you use [cordova plugin](https://github.com/hypery2k/cordova-hotspot-plugin/blob/master/PLUGIN_USAGE.MD#cordova.plugins.hotspot+pingHost) without ionic-native..

Comment: okay,thanks @suraj